# Efficient way to compute eigenvalue decomposition for following problem

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, matrix-analysis, convex-optimization, eigenvalues, eigenvector

I have an optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & Tr(X^TAX) \\  \text{subject to} & X^TX=I
\end{array}$$

where $A\in R^{n \times n}$ and it is symmetric positive definite, $X \in {n \times k}$ and $k \ll n$

I need to compute the $XX^T$ efficiently.

We know the above optimization $X$ can be solve by find the $k$ eigenvectors of $A$. but eigenvalue-decomposition take expensive time. Is there any approximation algorithm since I only need $XX^T$.

Answer (score 1):

- *Holodnak, John T.; Ipsen, Ilse C. F.*, [**Randomized approximation of the Gram matrix: exact computation and probabilistic bounds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/130940116), SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl. 36, No. 1, 110-137 (2015). [ZBL1330.65061](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1330.65061).
- *Drineas, Petros; Mahoney, Michael W.*, [**On the Nyström method for approximating a gram matrix for improved kernel-based learning**](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v6/drineas05a.html), J. Mach. Learn. Res. 6, 2153-2175 (2005). [ZBL1222.68186](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1222.68186).